# How to set length of slider in Primefaces (JSF)?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My code in ICEfaces (ACE Component), i have to change into Primefaces. There is conflict when i set length of Primefaces slider.

**Sample ICEfaces (ACE Component) code:**

```
<ace:sliderEntry id="slide" length="500px" min="0" max="1000" value="#{cal.value}" />
```

When i come up with Primefaces, i did't find any attribute named **length** to set length of slider.

**Sample Primefaces code:**

```
<p:slider id="slide" minValue="0" maxValue="1000" value="#{cal.value}" />
```

Now, How to set length of slider in Primefaces (JSF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the desired width in the style or styleClass of your component

**Style**

```
<p:slider for="txt2" display="output" style="width:200px" .....>
```

---

**StyleClass:**

In your xhtml:

```
<p:slider for="txt2" display="output" styleClass="slider_style" .....>
```

In your CSS:

```
.slider_style{
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: yeah., it works fine... But, we don't have any implicit attribute to set length?

Comment: Its quite common to set the width of the components in `style` using Primefaces...only a few components have that property. Also...try to search for "width" instead of "length" in the next time, you'll find more answers :)